# Api HTTP OPSKINS.COM, SEND PARAMETHER

Tags: python, ipython

```
 Much like Steam's WebAPI, requests to our API use the format  https://api.opskins.com/IInterfaceName/MethodName/v1/. Most requests should           гse the GET method, but some (specially marked) methods require POSTs.

Most requests require authentication. Those that don't are marked. To authenticate, you'll need your API key from your account page. We prefer that you send your key as your username in HTTP Basic authorization, but you can also supply it as a key GET or POST parameter (depending on the request method).
```

Show an example of how all the same to pass an API key. 
I do not understand

Answer (score 1):

The API key parameter is called `key`.

Example: `https://api.opskins.com/IInventory/GetInventory/v1/?key=YOUR_KEY_HERE`